# sql (reporting services) field split and find

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a field, which contains an address with comma separations like:
always some code and then description

"19415 - City" (different city has a different code)
"ABTH - sites" (always 4 digits and have a "TH" in the end, only the first 2 letters change)
"ABCD - building" (always 4 different letters)
and more place describing data, but those are not required

in the query I can split into 3 columns with

`=fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(0)` and in the column I change the `(0)` to `(1)` or `(2)`

but the input is mixed up in some cases

thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of the complete input (the content of A_hiba_helye) along with an example of the output from your split expression.

Comment: the problem is not the mixing up, because the error is in the input data.
i wuld like to have a query or code that picks just the city or just the sites or just the building from the comma sepadated listing
the listing goes like these:
19415 - Pécs , AKTH - Akác utcai telephely , AKGA - AKGA - Gyógyító 1. ---or---
RKTH - Rákóczi (BMK) telephely , 19415 - Pécs , RKAE - KK Rákóczi A-épület
from this i want to get the city, or the sites or the rest

Comment: You probably need to look at regular expressions, you can use Regex to parse the input data and pick out the correct characters. Search for 'Regex in SSRS'.
Alternatively you could do this in your query using LIKE, PATINDEX etc and have the 3 columns sent to your report making the SSRS side of things easier.

Comment: i managed to do some coding, and now, i can get the city by `InStr` like: `=switch(InStr(fields!A_hiba_helye.Value, "19415") > 0, "Pécs",
InStr(fields!A_hiba_helye.Value, "11730") > 0, "Orfű",
InStr(fields!A_hiba_helye.Value, "16115") > 0, "Pellérd")`
but now for the sites is a bit more difficult, because i've got abou 30 of them, and didnt know the names for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to solve the problem.
for the cities i used `InStr` just like above,
and for the sites and buildings i used `iif`s:
sor the sites:

```
=iif(fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(0).contains("TH"), fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(0),
(iif(fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(1).contains("TH"), fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(1), fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(2) )) )
```

and for the buildings:

```
=iif(fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(0).contains("TH") Or (fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(1).contains("TH")),
fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(2),
(iif(fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(1).contains("TH"), fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(2), fields!A_hiba_helye.Value.split(",")(1) )) )
```